# 2 Divs: Right-Centered, Left-overhang

Tags: css, html

I have a parent div, and 2 child divs. I want [child 2] to be centered in the parent. And I want [child 1] to hang over the left side of the parent. If I I give [child 1] a position of absolute, I can make the child left-hang outside of the container. However, [child 2] is still vertically displaced by the height of [child 1].

```
[c1][   [c2]   ]
```

I've worked up an example in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twashing/j7Pbn/2/). Any insight is appreciated.

Thanks 
Tim

Comment: Another point: why are you using `H4` for slide content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.slide-left-overhang` (which is child 1, right?) has `position: relative`. Set it to `position: absolute` and it won't interfere anymore.

Other notes:
`.slide-container-content` has a width that is greater than its containing element - set it to 100% or whatever width you want the text to be, and then set your margin autos.

You set a bunch of `<p>` tags inside of an `<h4>` - I'm not sure what you plan to do with that, but it's semantically troubling.

here, see my update (minor tweaks) of yours: http://jsfiddle.net/Ye5us/

Answer (score 0):

Use this structure:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="div_container"> 

    <div class="div_left">

    </div>

    <div class="div_right">

        <div class="div_right_content">

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
div {

    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    background: yellow;

}

.div_container {

    width: 500px;
    margin: 0px auto;

}

.div_left {

    width: 200px;
    float: left;

}

.div_right {

    width: 300px;
    float: right;
    background: blue;

}

.div_right_content {

    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;

}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xk7fP/1/